# \listoftable affects next page

Tags: table-of-contents

The header of the list of tables is carry forwarded to next section also, i.e. Abstract page header shows LIST OF TABLES!

```
\tableofcontents  %%% INCLUDE THESE LATER
\clearpage
\listoffigures  %%% INCLUDE THESE LATER
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\listoftables   %%% INCLUDE THESE LATER
%\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
\include{Abstract/Abstract}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` after `\listoftables` could help

Comment: Use `\markboth{}{}` or, if you want something to go to the toc, use [unnumberedtotoc](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc).